# How do I retrieve Email-ID from auth_user table in Django?

Tags: django, django-1.5

How do I retrieve Email-ID from auth_user table in Django?
 I am getting only id and username if I access the auth_user table.

### Models.py

```
class AuthUser(models.Model):
id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField()
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField()
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField()
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField()

class Meta:
    db_table = 'auth_user'

def as_json(self):
    return dict(
        user_id=self.id,
        username=self.username,
        email=self.email
    )
```

---

### views.py

```
class UserViewSet(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = AuthUserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        q = self.kwargs['username']
        if q != '*':
            return AuthUser.objects.filter(username=q)
        else:
            return AuthUser.objects.all()
```

---

### urls.py

```
url(r'^getUserData/(?P<username>.+)/$',
                                                  views.UserViewSet.as_view(),
                                                  name='user-details'),
```

---

I need only email from AuthUser object

Comment: Are you using the standard django user object? Imported like this: from django.contrib.auth.models import User

Comment: Post your auth_user model code

Comment: @kujosHeist:  Posted the code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a template? Your view class should specify which html file you want to use to render the view

i.e.

`template_name = 'app/template.html'`

Check out the example here in the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/

You can then have the following code in your tamplate to list the user emails

```
     <ul>
        {% for user in object_list %}
            <li>{{ user.email }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

Comment: I do not want to render the view at  HTML. Instead, I want to pass user email address to a function which sends an email.

Comment: $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      contentType: 'application/json',
      url: "/send_alert_email/",
      data: '{ "recipient" : '+user.email+', "alert_message" : "' + alert_flu_shot_message+'"}',
      dataType: "json",
      }).done(function(){
      console.log("Email sent");
     }).error(function(){
      console.log("Email not sent.");
     });